# How do I set environment variable for node launched on remote machine?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a launch file which runs some nodes on a remote machine.  I declare the remote machine as follows:

```
  <machine name="petra" address="petra" env-loader="/home/paul/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/env.sh"/>
```

and launch a remote node with:

```
  <node machine="petra" name="myspeech.py" pkg="speech_infinite" type="myspeech.py" output="screen"/>
```

The node uses Google cloud speech API and requires an environment variable of the form:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/paul/Programs/GoogleAccount/myproject-blahblah.json
```

Currently I edit env.sh in devel_isolated, but that gets overwritten when I *make* the workspace.

I have traced through the shell scripts, which include other scripts, which include other scripts and hooks etc. It left my head spinning !  Can anyone suggest a good way(i.e. minimal changes to ROS boilerplate)  to set this up, so that:

1. The Google credentials are included even after remaking catkin workspace
2. All the rest of my catkin environment continues to be loaded.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381675/how-do-i-set-environment-variable-for-node-launched-on-remote-machine-?/) by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2021-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Tried using env-loader to just run a seperate bash script?](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/machine#Examples)
You could source the "/home/paul/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/env.sh" from the other "start_script.sh" if necessary?

```
<node machine="petra" name="myspeech.py" pkg="speech_infinite" type="myspeech.py" env-loader="/suitable_directory/start_script.sh" output="screen"/>
```

Alternatively put the export in your /etc/profile or ~/.bashrc on the remote machine?

---

Originally posted by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) with karma: 525 on 2021-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on 2021-07-03**:
Thanks for your suggestion.  It seems blindingly obvious now, but at the time I was reeling from trying to follow what was going on with all the indirection.  I thought I had to go via the provided env file.  Following your idea, I made a file on the remote machine ,called env.bash, which works perfectly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#This allows use of Google speech recognition and other cloud services.
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/paul/Programs/GoogleAccount/zen-speech-2bcd94a51876.json"

source /home/paul/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/setup.bash
exec "$@"
```

The launch file contains:

```
<machine name="petra" address="petra" env-loader="/home/paul/catkin_ws/src/env.bash"/>
```